# how to create a webpage that can display other local webpages

Tags: php, html, iis

I have a bunch of websites running on various ports that are accessible on my lan, I want to be able to access these sites from a central webpage from the internet without the sites being access directly (I only want port 80 open to the wan). I guess it is like a web portal to my intranet

I hope that make sense.

I figure it would need to do something along the lines of a iframe with url to the internal site, however this obviously wont work as html is processed on the client side.

from previous experience there is always away, maybe with php???

That is were I need your help, any suggestions of a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a web page with content of any URL using PHP.

Create .php files for each local sites:

in site1.php

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://you_local_url:any_port');
echo $content;
```

in site2.php

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://you_another_local_url:any_port');
echo $content;
```

Then, create a index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
...
<a href="site1.php">Site1</a>
<a href="site2.php">Site2</a>
...
</html>
```

Use index.html on 80 port to show any local sites.

**But this shows only first pages of the sites :(**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request correctly, the best way to achieve that is configuring your webserver (IIS, Apache, or whatever is used as the local web server) to load the websites as different subdirectories of your domain, instead of different ports. and then you can have access to all websites at port 80.

Comment: yes that is it in essince however the other sites have there own webservers, is there a way to make iis work with that?

Comment: Oh, do you mean the websites are hosted on different machines (different IPs) and with different web servers?

Comment: Hi, Geez this is a bit old now :), I ended up ditching the idea as it was a bit over my head. but essential I wanted a public facing website that would sort of act as a reverse web proxy to my internal networks services, I had 4 pagess running on different ports ie 80, 81, 8080 & 8081 and was wanting to make a gateway type page that would proxy to them so i wouldn't have to keep changing urls

does that make sence.

Anywho, thanks but I gave up :)